# If you’re going to ham it up, go the whole hog

Tags: meaning-in-context, idioms

Please help me to understand it

> If you’re going to ham it up, go the whole hog.  — G. I. Gurdjieff

Is the 'ham' a meat? What is a 'hog' here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The author uses two idioms:

[To ham it up](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ham_it_up) - deliberately exaggerate one's emotions or movements, or to overact or act badly.

[To go the whole hog](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/go_the_whole_hog) - to  do something as entirely or completely as possible; to reserve or hold back nothing.

The combination of these two idioms is humorous because both relate to pigs.

Comment: With a pun, since ham comes from hogs.

Comment: And there is a variant form, "go whole hog" without the article, with the same meaning.